# TestMain not run

Tags: go, goland

I have a test package in go which tests some stuff that depend on reading a configuration. I want to read that configuration once before running all tests so I'm trying to use `TestMain(m *testing.M)`:

main.go:

```
package tests

import (
    ...
)

var logger = logging.MustGetLogger("tests")

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    logger.Info("Initializing test suite")

    viper.SetConfigName("config")
    viper.AddConfigPath("..\\..\\")
    err := viper.ReadInConfig()
    if err == nil {
        os.Exit(m.Run())
    } else {
        logger.Fatal("Could not read configuration")
    }
}
```

And I have another file in the same directory (and package) with a test.

repository_test.go:

```
package tests

import (
    ...
)

func TestCreation(t *testing.T) {
    aa := myModule.CreateRepository()
    assert.NotNil(t, aa)
}
```

My problem is that the test fails because the configuration is not read from the file. When I try to debug the test in Gogland a breakpoint inside `TestMain` is not hit. When I run the tests from command line I don't see any printouts from `TestMain`.

Is there something special I should do to make it work? From what I read online I understood that if I define `TestMain(m *testing.M)` then it's going to run just once for the package and that's where I'm supposed to write any setup or teardown code.

Comment: All files in the test suite (including the file which defines `TestMain`) must ends  with `*_test.go`. Rename it to e.g. `main_test.go`

Comment: @putu omg! That must be it. I feel like an idiot now. Will check once I'm near my computer!

Comment: Yes, indeed that was the thing. Well, at least now I'm sure this will never ever happen to me again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[TestMain](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Main) is only executed in test files (suffix `_test.go`).

Move the function to the repository_test.go file to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the run configuration is set to Package not File in Run | Edit Configurations... | Go Test | Name of your configuration and this should work. If it doesn't, please post the commands the IDE runs to execute the tests.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not next to my computer now. I'll try this later. But what about running from command line? I need this to work on TeamCity as well. On TeamCity we use 'go test -v path/tests'

Comment: That's the difference between running a specific file and a Package (or Directory). In TeamCity, unless you specify all the files manually, that path looks like a directory / package. Go will only run the Test functions in a single file if you specify that file. Please let me know if the configuration change helped or not.